# Accepting nested attributes on single table inheritance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, strong-parameters, single-table-inheritance

I'm trying to get rid of duplication of strong params in controller that handles STI models. For example I have models:

```
class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
  has many :fruits
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :fruits, allow_destroy :true
end

class Fruit < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :recipe
end

class Apple < Fruit
end

class Orange < Fruit
end

class RecipesController < Admin::BaseController
  ...
  def update
   @recipe.update_attributes recipe_params
  end
  ...
  def recipe_params
    params.require(:recipe).permit( :some_recipe_params
                                    ...
                                    ??? )
  end
end
```

Is there any convenient way to permit 'apple_attributes' and 'orange_attributes' without repeating them in permit options ? In future application will have more fruit types. Or maybe fruit models should be handled in another controller.

I found an ugly way to do it with whitelisted:

```
params.require(:recipe).permit( ... ).tap do |whitelisted|
  Recipe.fruit_types.each do |type|
    whitelisted[:"#{type.pluralize}_attributes"] = params[:recipe][:"#{type.pluralize}_attributes"] || {}
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Permit should looks like this:

```rb
params.require(:recipe).permit fruits: [:id, :_type, ...]
```

Attribute "_type" must be present for all fruits otherwise you can permit only attributes from base model (Fruit)